# YouTube Api Explorer Usuage as ContentOwner: forbidden

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'd like to get the impressionBasedCpm from the Api Explorer ( and later from my app).

I can log in with an youtube partner account and toggle the oauth switch. I set all scopes to checked.

Then I try to enter

ids: contentOwner==NAME_OF_CONTENT_OWNER (not the id, retrieved from the content API, https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/contentOwners/list#try-it)

metrics: impressionBasedCpm

start-date: '2015-05-01'
end-date:   '2015-06-01'

The output still tells me:

You do not have permission to execute this method.

Can someone help me?

My guess is that when I authorize the application I seam to still login as a channel, so the query as a content owner is not allowed. I picked the main one with the email address. But when I'm on youtube I can switch to a specific Content-Manager Channel/Account.

Even when I try to just get the 'likes' for the contentOwner it doesn't work. If I try to get the likes based on the channel_id it works. But I like to get reports for a youtube partner that uses youtube's cms.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

This query won't work because it does not follow the semantics of the API. You need to provide the ID of the contentOwner in order to get a 200 OK response. Name of Content Owner cannot be unique and hence would lead to erroneous results.